# What tech is Jaguar Land Rover + UK government looking to ban?

Tags: united-kingdom, technology

[The BBC is reporting](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-68188064) that Jaguar Land Rover said the technology used by criminal gangs to steal their cars should be illegal and the company was working with the government to help get laws changed.  My understanding is that this is in response to security vulnerabilities exploited with the use of radio frequency receivers/transmitters connected to generic computing hardware.

What proposals have been made to criminalise modern technology used to steal cars?

Answer (score 10):

There are already laws that apply and could be used.  Specifically [the 1968 theft act makes a crime of "Going equipped:](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/section/25)

> A person shall be guilty of an offence if, when not at his place of abode, he has with him any article for use in the course of or in connection with any burglary or theft.

The main use of this is to allow the police to arrest people carrying lockpicks (etc) even without evidence that they had committed a theft.

The issues in getting convictions under this law come down to the difficulty of proving intent. Radiofrequency transmitters are not themselves illegal. But carrying a radiofrequency transmitter which is capable of emitting the coded signals of car locks, *with the purpose of stealing a car* is illegal.  A second issue is detection, since such items are small and easily concealed, and may not be recognised as "equipment" by a non-specialist police officer.

Comment: Does there need to be evidence of intent to commit crime to be convicted of "going equiped". For instance, crimes involving lockpicks are quite rare. Lacking other evidence, it would seem more likely that someone carrying lockpicks is a locksmith or practicing locksports. Or is it guilty until proven innocent?

Comment: There is a section of the act that says "proof that he had with him any article made or adapted for use in committing a burglary or theft shall be evidence that he had it with him for such use". So if you are carrying such items, you need to provide evidence that you had a legitimate reason.

Comment: Wow, any article which can be used for any burglary? This law is so vague, that in practice I could be arrested for having a screwdriver, because it can also be used for burglary. Or having a hairpin in my hair, because it can be used for lockpicking. The cynic in me says it's not a bug, it's a feature: governments like laws which are as general as possible so that anyone can be arrested for breaking them, because they can apply it to anyone they don't like.

Comment: @vsz "made or adapted for" – Although cannot be applied in every case without doubt, of course, this is the main part. A screwdriver or a hairpin is not _made for_ and probably not even _adapted for_ this purpose, even if it can be used for this purpose. (Aside but this reminds me of the standard "counterargument" of gun proponents: "we might just as well ban knives or cars because...". That's exactly what they fail to consider: those are not made for this specific purpose, even if sometimes used for killing, while guns are).

Comment: Agreed but I'd add three things. (i) The Wireless Telegraphy Act generally prohibits somebody receiving a signal he is not permitted to receive. So broadly speaking, if something isn't in one of the ISM or broadcast bands it's already illegal to receive it. (ii) Some vehicle manufacturers use woefully weak "security by obscurity" which could in principle be cracked using a minimal DVB "stick" attached to a mobile 'phone (neither illegal). (iii) There are already adequate laws relating to "uttering false identification" etc. The bottom line is we need properly-informed lawyers and politicians.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd And it also helps if manufacturers get it right and don't simply expect the law to make it right instead of them. Dreaming, for sure... :-)

Comment: While the car manufacturers and their dealers should bear responsibility for putting something "not fit for purpose" on the market, the original offenders are often the companies who make the keyfob electronics. Honda comes out of this extremely badly for trying to stonewall the CVE process hence the US Department of Homeland Security, but https://i.blackhat.com/USA-22/Thursday/US-22-Csikor-RollBack-A-New-Time-Agnostic-Replay-Attack.pdf p29 indicates that multiple manufacturers are affected by the same bug: and that's just one of the many known.

Comment: @Gábor : the article cited in the answer does not contain "made or adapted for". It's merely about possessing something which can be used for such a purpose.

Comment: @vsz . I'm afraid it does, (3).

Comment: @Gábor : are the (1) and (3) in an "or" relation or in an "and" relation? If not in an "and" relation, then according to (1), you could be charged with possessing anything which can be used for burglary.

Comment: @vsz : I think it's quite clear, there are two ways to be guilty. Either (1) you have any tool (it could be a handkerchief) but you actually have to use it for burglary/theft, or (3) you have a tool specifically made or modified for burglary/theft, then you don't need to use it, just having it on you is enough. I can't actually see any fault with the text or the intention here. It clearly doesn't cover innocent tools in innocent situations.

Comment: Yes, the language "used, made or adapted" is similar to that for weapons.  A gun is made as a weapon,  a broken bottle is adapted, a screwdriver thrust at someone is used as a weapon.

Comment: @Gábor (1) does not say I have to actually have used it. It says "for use", and not that I actually used it.

Comment: @vsz: "for use in the course of or in connection with". OK, let's rest the case. To me, it's entirely clear: either any tool but actually used for crime (usage proves the intent), or specific criminal tool even if not used (its purpose proves the intent). If you can't see it from the text, I won't be able to convince you any further.

Comment: @Gábor I'm all for gun control, but I don't think the laws should be formulated in terms of banning items "made for killing" and be this vague in terms of when they apply or not. I think the laws should be more specific about what constitutes a gun and under what circumstances it is legal or illegal to own, store and transport it. That enables citizens to be sure that they comply with the terms of whatever lawful usage the lawmakers may have envisioned. The "going equipped" formulation has the hallmarks of a rubber law inviting convictions based on whims and prejudice.

Comment: @jkej Well, why not. I'm not British, so all I can do is to view it from afar. If you are or if you know British people who want that law changed, this is probably a worthy hill to die on. :-))

Comment: Actually the problem with this law is not that it is used capriciously, but rather that it has been hard to get police and prosecutors to use it at all, except in the most obvious cases.  That is why Jaguar etc are looking for specific laws.

Comment: @Gábor I'm not British, just thought it sounded like a poorly drafted law. Glad to hear that this has led to lackluster enforcement, rather than what I had imagined.